# How do I insert a split line in an Activity Diagram using UML 2.0 plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, uml, activity-diagram

I'm using UML 2.0 plugin on Eclipse for creating some activity diagrams. I would like to insert some split lines (the horizontal bold lines used for expressing concurrence) but I can't find the relative button in the Palette on the right. Also, I can't find any help on the web.

Thank you for any answer and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What is a "split line"? You mean a SwimLane (Activity Partitions) or a Fork? What plugin are you using? Papyrus? TopCased?

Comment: @seya, I understand you meant a Fork/Join but with no reference to the tool it's really hard to help... please tell which tool did you use.